# Live tile interface

Tags: customization, user-interface, windows-mobile

I was just viewing my friend's Lumia 535 who has Windows 10 mobile installed on it which really inspired me. That OS possess a very well-integrated customizable tiled interface. I really loved that UI. Most remarkable were the aliveness and transparency of tiles. Can we have a tile interface like windows phone? As far as I know android is fa more customizable and bug-less as compared o windows but that thing really impressed me. So I was thinking as if it were possible?

Comment: Plenty of alternative launchers like what @Komninos posted, but they all affect the homescreen only. It will be tremendous and impossible work to rework the framework to show everything (i.e. apps) in live tiles.

Comment: Yup @AndyYan I was also sad because of the same reason. It provides that   interface but nothing live in it. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an app called [Launcher 8 WP style](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lx.launcher8&hl=en) for that.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Yup you helped............+1.......It was good but not as I thgought it :/